# how to set up a new interface without an ip ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, openstack, interface

So i'm trying to set up a working openstack infrastracture and i need to make a new interface without an actual ip address, problem is that when i edit the /etc/network/interfaces, the new interface i make doesn't go up despite running ifup or restarting the system, i already used the new network manager to setup a working static ip but i do not know how to use it to make this new interface without ip thing on it.

here is the document i'm following :

https://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-ubuntu/environment-networking-controller.html

help please,
thank you,

Comment: Does it give you an error when you run ifup?

Comment: yes, it says interface doesn't exist, besides the interface really doesn't show up when executing "ifconfig", do you know how to do it using network manager ?

Comment: post the output of "ifconfig -a". Also try using "sudo ifconfig <interface> up" instead

Answer (score 0):

```
ifconfig ethX up
```

or

```
ifconfig ethX 0.0.0.0
```

will do the job...

Please be aware that its not persistent.